# Open CV Camera error - Green color Flickering during initialising

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am working in an Project where open cv is used to detect the colors. Everything works fine but whenever the camera is initialised, I am getting a green color flickering in camera which lasts for a second and then goes off.

The code i am using for initialising opencv camera is,

```
 if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this,mLoaderCallback);
        }
```

I am attaching the images for your reference. 
First Image - During Green color Flickering.

Second Image - After flickering, camera working normally.

Any heads up would be helpful for my learning.

[image: Green color flickering for an second]

[image: Normal camera after the green color flickering]

Comment: Have you tried it on some other devices?

Comment: Yes , Its occuring in all devices

Comment: Do you know whether your initDebug returns true or false?

Comment: Its returning true !

Answer (score 0):

You are probably initializing your OpenCV with `initAsync` method. As the name implies, it initializes OpenCV in the background while your app(which means your UI thread) is working. You can test it with putting some notifier in `mLoaderCallback` function. Your camera view probably fixed when that function is called. If that is the case, disable your view until you get to initialization callback. Similar questions:
[android opencv green flash](http://answers.opencv.org/question/18638/android-opencv-green-flash/)
[JavaCameraView flashing green screen bug](http://answers.opencv.org/question/35715/javacameraview-flashing-green-screen-bug/)